# Apache 2.4 cross domain

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, cors, cross-domain

I have ubuntu 16.04 and apache 2.4 and mod_headers enabled. I have an https site with configuration in default-ssl.conf that is using an http site in port 8000 in the same apache in 000-default configuration file.

I have created my certificate with certbot. I have tried all Headers set access and still apache is not accepting http link. Now I have this in default-ssl:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-
Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Is it possible that the problem is the certificate? The browser is accepting the cerificate but is not accepting cross domain.
An error example : Loading mixed (insecure) display content “http://ipaddresss//appointments.png” on a secure page

Comment: What do you mean by *“apache is not accepting http link”*? You instead mean “https”? Either way, what does “not accepting” mean? What exact error message are you seeing, or what exactly are you expecting to happen that’s not happening? Regardless, this would seem to not have anything to do with CORS. The only thing the `Access-Control-*` headers affect is whether browsers will allowed frontend JavaScript code to access responses for requests made using XHR or the Fetch API.

Comment: This is the error: Loading mixed (insecure) display content http://ipaddress/appointments.png” on a secure page

Comment: Thanks I see that you updated your answer to add that detail. So the problem is that somewhere in your content you have a code or markup or CSS that's either requesting `http://ipaddresss//appointments.png`, or else that the server is redirecting requests for `https://ipaddresss//appointments.png` (https) to `http://ipaddresss//appointments.png` (non-https).

Comment: Isn't possible to use an http link inside an https? I have read that with these headers you can use http links inside https.

Comment: No, it is not possible to use embedded http resources inside https documents. Doing so will cause browsers to emit mixed-content errors just like the one cited in your question. No headers you add on the server side will cause browsers to ignore the mixed-content errors. There is no way to avoid them (except to ensure that all the content is served using https).

Comment: I have managed to make it work in apache 2.2. Maybe in apache 2.4 is not possible anymore. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work. For anyone interested. I added both virtualhosts (port 443 and 80) in /etc/apache/sites-available/000-default.conf. I disabled ssl site and enabled only 000-default

```
a2dissite default-ssl
a2ensite 000-default
```

and I have also added inside   inside VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```